# NodeJS mysql - Managing Multiple MySQL DB with 1 connection

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to use multiple db with 1 connection to MySQL server with a user. I am making a web server but it will get connections from multiple hostnames like example.com example2.com and they will have a panel to manage their page. Then they will have these credentials to connect: username, password and db name. So they can integrate to other things they want. But while we are creating a pool we specify a database and I want to optimize db connection so I don't want to create multiple connections. I am using mysql2 with multiple db connections for now.
Thanks!

Comment: What problem are you having with multiple database connections? Are these multiple databases on a single server?

Comment: I have these databases on same server there is no problem for the start but after having like 50 webpages I think it's not a good option to connect to same server with 50 connections to get 50 databases. I want to have single connection.

Comment: Why do you need so many databases? That also doesn't seem like it will scale very well.

Comment: I will get requests from the webpages (example.com, other.com ...) and I need to use different databases for each webpage. Because they will have different user accounts with different database access, only access to his to integrate other things.

Comment: I think I found a method. I will try it and say the answer asap after my lessons. I will try an SQL query like this: 

SELECT value
 FROM `database1`.`settings`
  WHERE name="hostname"
for other
SELECT value
 FROM `database2`.`settings`
  WHERE name="hostname"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I used a query like this:

```
SELECT value FROM databaseName.tableName WHERE name="something"
```